# Get unique nodes based on attribute value xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the below xml in a variable, I need to get the unique nodes in xslt 1.0

```
    <out2:PrintRequest>
        <Passenger FirstNameNumber="01" LastNameNumber="01"/>
        <Passenger FirstNameNumber="01" LastNameNumber="02"/>
        <Passenger FirstNameNumber="01" LastNameNumber="01"/>
        <Passenger FirstNameNumber="01" LastNameNumber="02"/>
    </out2:PrintRequest>
```

=================================
output expected:

```
    <out2:PrintRequest>
        <Passenger FirstNameNumber="01" LastNameNumber="01"/>
        <Passenger FirstNameNumber="01" LastNameNumber="02"/>
    </out2:PrintRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Meunchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) for grouping by creating an `xsl:key` for the `Passenger` elements using the values from the `@FirstNameNumber` and `@LastNameNumber` attributes to construct the key's lookup value, iterate over each of the `Passenger` elements and copy the element if it is the first element retrieved from the `xsl:key` for that grouping key value.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:out2="out2">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="passengers-by-num" match="Passenger" use="concat(@FirstNameNumber,@LastNameNumber)"/>

  <xsl:template match="out2:PrintRequest">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Passenger[generate-id() = generate-id(key('passengers-by-num', concat(@FirstNameNumber,@LastNameNumber)[1]))]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>          
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you can use **XSLT 2.0** (or 3.0), then this would be a little easier. You could use [xsl:for-each-group](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PER-xslt20-20090421/#xsl-for-each-group):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:out2="out2">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="out2:PrintRequest">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Passenger" group-by="concat(@FirstNameNumber,@LastNameNumber)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>          
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```